# OpenCover shows code coverage for C# projects but not C++ CLI native project

Tags: c#, c++, nunit, code-coverage, opencover

I have a large visual 2013 solution composed of 20+ projects paired with test projects that use NUnit for unit testing.  All of these projects are straight C# except one with that wraps an external C++ class which uses C++ CLI. The wrapper class is unit tested in C#.  OpenCover displays the info for all of the C# classes including the parent classes of the wrapper but excludes the coverage for the C++ methods.  Is this a limitation of NUnit and/or OpenCover or "user" error?

When I peer into the output directory, I can see the wrapper class xml, dll, and pdb.  When I run ReportGenerator on the native dll's xml, I can see the C# classes.

Comment: It can only handle managed code.  Getting code coverage for native code is a much harder problem to solve.  Maybe you ought to leave that up to [Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2011/08/16/capturing-c-code-coverage-with-visual-c.aspx).

Comment: This looks similar to this issue https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/198